# jquery ajax post passing empty value to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this jquery script inside $(document).ready to post data to my database

```
 $('#btnSaveStatus').on('click', function () {
    //$('#btnSumitChanges').click()
    var stid = $('#StoreID').val()
    var oStid = $('#oldStatus').val()
    var ddlID = $('#ddlStatusDef').val()
    var strUrl = $('#txtUrl').val()
    debugger;
    if (oStid != ddlID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: strUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'apllication/html; charset=utf-8',
            data:{'sToreid': stid,'StatusDefid': ddlID},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#DivStatus').modal('hide');
            }

        })
    }
```

here is my action

```
        public ActionResult ChangeStoreStatus(string sToreid, string StatusDefid)
    {
```

}
the sToreid and StatusDefid are null in the action method even though in the script the value are sent correctly. They're not received
Can someone help me find out what is wrong here?

Regards

Comment: `contentType: 'apllication/html; charset=utf-8',` Typo? `application`

Comment: thx but same problem

Comment: Actually just remove that line and see what you get. `contentType` is supposed to be the format you are sending data to the server

Comment: Totally nail it @Arleigh Hix, thank you!

Comment: explained in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the docs the option `contentType` is for data sent *to* the server. You are not sending html. Just remove that declaration and allow the default 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' to be used.

> All settings are optional.
> ...
> **contentType** (default:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
> Type: Boolean or String
> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default
> is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine
> for most cases. ...
>
> — https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/